# How can I delete a specific variable from my PATH environment variable using fish shell

Tags: shell, scripting, fish

Given an input variable say usr/bin and the following PATH

```
 echo $PATH 
 /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/sbin /Developer/bin
```

how can I write (in fish shell) a function that given the string/input can delete that path from my PATH variable? 
->Ideally one that deletes the first occurrence (vs one that deletes all occurrences of such variable)

I was considering writing a small function such as

```
deleteFromPath usr/bin
```

Would it be better to write this in a scripting language like Perl/python/ruby rather than in fish shell?

```
for x in $list
    if [ $x = $argv ]
        //delete element x from list -> How?
    end
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're jumping to perl/python/ruby rather than, say, a POSIX shell?

Comment: `IFS=: read -r -a path_entries <<<"$PATH"; for idx in "${!path_entries[@]}"; do for arg; do [[ ${path_entries[$idx]} = "$arg" ]] && unset path_entries[$idx]; done; done; printf -v PATH '%s:' "${path_entries[@]}"; PATH=${PATH%':'}` strikes me as a fairly sane implementation for bash that's cautious about correctness. fish really isn't built for scripting; it's very much an *interactive* shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `fish` doesn't support `POSIX` Substring Removal techniques?

Comment: @Inian, fish wasn't written as a POSIX shell at all. They could have borrowed any given feature, but I'm not going to spend time learning which they did or didn't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Cheers! just wanted to clarify it, before posting an answer using the same! :)

Comment: @Inian, ...also, PATH isn't a string in fish at all -- it's a "list", their version of arrays. By all means, go ahead and post any tested fish-native answer you have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is rather easy to do in fish.

With `set -e`, you can erase not just entire variables, but also elements from lists, like `set -e PATH[2]` to delete the second element (fish counts list indices from 1).

With `contains -i`, you can find which index an element is at.

So you'll want to call `set -e PATH[(contains -i $argv $PATH)]`.

With some error-handling and edgecases fixed, this'd look like

```
 function deleteFromPath
     # This only uses the first argument
     # if you want more, use a for-loop
     # Or you might want to error `if set -q argv[2]`
     # The "--" here is to protect from arguments or $PATH components that start with "-"
     set -l index (contains -i -- $argv[1] $PATH)
     # If the contains call fails, it returns nothing, so $index will have no elements
     # (all variables in fish are lists)
     if set -q index[1]
         set -e PATH[$index]
     else
         return 1
     end
  end
```

Note that this compares the path *strings*, so you'd need to call `deleteFromPath /usr/bin`, with the leading "/". Otherwise it would not find the component.

Answer (score -2):

We can call through to bash. :)

```
function removePathElements
    set PATH (bash -c 'IFS=: read -r -a path_entries <<<"$PATH"; for idx in "${!path_entries[@]}"; do for arg; do [[ ${path_entries[$idx]} = "$arg" ]] && unset path_entries[$idx]; done; done; printf "%s\n" "${path_entries[@]}"' _ $argv)
end
```

To be clear, the embedded bash code here is:

```
IFS=: read -r -a path_entries <<<"$PATH"
for idx in "${!path_entries[@]}"; do
  for arg; do
    [[ ${path_entries[$idx]} = "$arg" ]] && unset path_entries[$idx]
  done
done
printf "%s\n" "${path_entries[@]}"
```

Comment: To be clear -- this definitely isn't a great answer, and the fish-native accepted answer *deserves* to be accepted and has my upvote. On the other hand, AFAICT there's nothing *wrong* about this one, which is why I'm leaving it in place (and would appreciate an explanation, as opposed to a bare downvote, if there actually *is* a respect in which it's incorrect as opposed to merely verbose and inefficient).